# Bloquear Spinner usando Switch en Android Studio con Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-spinner

Quiero bloquear el cambio de Spinner al momento de usar el Switch, pero no se como hacer para que el Spinner no cambie, por el momento solo capturo el evento de cambio de Switch de esta manera:

```
    private fun blockSpinner(){
    val block = findViewById<SwitchMaterial>(R.id.block)
    block?.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ _, isChecked ->
        if(isChecked){
            campus.isEnabled()<-- Estuve probando de esta manera.
            //campus.isEnabled = true <-- Y de esta manera también, y no logre hacerlo. 
        }
    }
}
```

Estuve buscando en la documentación y no llegue a dar con lo que necesito, agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto únicamente sirve para obtener si esta habilitado o no

```
spinner.isEnabled()
```

si deseas deshabilitar un `Spinner` lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
spinner.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: Perfecto amigo, me sirvió, muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente @JOSEMORIANO , saludos!